# Confidence interval for mean concentration of pesticide residue in vegetables becomes negative

Tags: confidence-interval

We analyzed pesticide residues in tomatoes, cabbages and chards. When I calculated the **95%CI for concentration of some residues in vegetables**, it produces **negative values for lower bound**. For example, **95%CI for concentration of profenofos in cabbage** is (I used R for the computation):
ci_mean(c_data$prof_log)

```
ci_mean(c_data$prof_µg_per_kg)

Two-sided 95% t confidence interval for the population mean
```

Sample estimate: 0.3506604
Confidence interval:
2.5%      97.5%
***-0.3446344***  1.0459551

FYI, of the 106 cabbage samples, only one sample is positive for profenofos (profenofos was not detected in 105 samples) as follow:
table(c_data$prof_log)

```
          concentration  0         37.17
          n             105         1
```

I also tried log transformation (log1p(x)) if it works but it remains the same. I faced similar problems for the other pesticides detected in our study while reporting their CI or mean(SD).
What should I do to solve this problem?
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What's the problem?

Comment: What sort of CI do you want to see, given that 105 out of 106 samples showed no residual?   You might want to build a model that has an explicit term to capture the probability of exactly 0 pesticides detected...  the CI associated with the t-test is symmetric around the estimate, so if it's wide enough, it will include zero.   There are alternative methods of constructing CIs that avoid this problem, but zero should definitely be within the CI given the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a quick-and-dirty Bayesian interval using the "exact" interval calculator at https://sample-size.net/confidence-interval-proportion/

Another online calculator is available at https://causascientia.org/math_stat/ProportionCI.html#Technical%20Details which includes a very brief explanation of the method.